# How to read "CPU (ms/sec)" in the "Recent Expensive Queries" of Activity Monitor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is `CPU (ms/sec)` the cpu time in ms in previous second? If it reaches 1000, does it means that it uses 100% CPU?

However, on my 8 cores server, the `% Processor Time` is usually very low like several percent when the most expensive query in the "Recent Expensive Queries" reaches 1000.

Answer (score 10):

This is the ratio of CPU time used by that query per second. Internally to SQL Server in this DMV ([`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)) CPU time is measured in microseconds and the report is pulling the usage per second. However, the `ms` in the report is in *milliseconds* for the Activity Monitor and microsecond would be [`mcs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

The reason you're seeing 1000 in this result set ***could be*** because that query used all CPU time for that one-second interval. Restated, it has used 1000 ms of CPU time for that second. On a system with multiple schedulers ([`sys.dm_os_schedulers`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177526%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)), it is possible to have queries go parallel and use multiple schedulers and have > 1000ms/sec of CPU time. In your example below, 500ms of CPU time for the SQLOS scheduler has been consumed by that query in the last second. This means that 50% of one CPU's time was dedicated to this query. Note that it could have been a parallel query and only used 10% of five schedulers (which correlate to the number of CPUs). Depending on the timing of these parallel threads, it could present as low CPU usage in the `% Processor Time`. In your performance monitor are you looking at the `_Total` or per processor? Also, you can run the query below to see how SQL Server is reporting its own CPU utilization (thank you Glenn Berry).

```
DECLARE @ts_now BIGINT;
SELECT @ts_now = cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks)FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info;         
SELECT TOP(10) 
    SQLProcessUtilization AS sql_server_process_cpu,
    SystemIdle AS system_idle_process_cpu,
    100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS other_process_cpu,
    DATEADD(ms, -1 * (@ts_now - [timestamp]), GETDATE()) AS event_time
    FROM (
            SELECT 
                record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id,
                record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') AS [SystemIdle],
                record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]','int') AS [SQLProcessUtilization], 
                [timestamp]
            FROM (
                    SELECT [timestamp], convert(xml, record) AS [record]
                    FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
                    WHERE ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'
                        AND record LIKE '%<SystemHealth>%') AS x
                  ) AS y
    ORDER BY record_id DESC;
```

Do keep in mind that `total_worker_time` is the amount of CPU time used by the query since the plan was compiled*. Take a look at the `Executions/min` right next to the `CPU (ms/sec)` in the report to get a sense of whether or not this query plan has been used multiple times. Note: This may require math. Having said all of this, I fired up Activity Monitor and looked at one of the queries that was showing high CPU time on a development instance. I then went to the DMV to look at total_cpu_time for that query and the number is quite high (which is to be expected). This leads me to believe that the math is being handled internally by Activity Monitor and is taking the difference between current `total_cpu_time` and what it knew the `total_cpu_time` to be 1 second ago.

So in summary, this **is** showing you how much `total_cpu_time` in microseconds the query in question has used in the last second.

I'd also make a note of that query and look at the [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) results for that query plan hash and look at the other information provided by that DMV.

Comment: If the CPU time is in milliseconds per second, it would be reasonable for it to go up to 1000 per core tops, but I am running a query on an 8-way box and reading 397094. That's almost 50x times higher than expected then. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Mousing over the CPU (ms/sec) header in Activity Monitor advises looking at  sys.dm_exec_query_stats.total_worker_time in Books Online.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx

Here is the definition for total_worker_time:

Total amount of CPU time, in microseconds, that was consumed by executions of this plan since it was compiled.

In my experience, any performance metric stored in SQL Server that is per second is a cumulative value.  I hope this helps.

Frank

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the same by check the definition of `total_work_time` and it's what confused me. If it reach, for example, 500, so 50% of the CPU should be busy running the query. However the process time in either performance monitoring or `% Processor Time` is much lower.

Comment: @u23432534 ... no ... 500ms of CPU time for the SQLOS scheduler has been consumed by that query in the last second. This means that 50% of one CPU's time was dedicated to this query. Note that it could have been a parallel query and only used 10% of five schedulers (which correlate to the number of CPUs).